# Using Linux crypto API from User Space for RSA

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, rsa

I am looking for a way to call Linux kernel crypto API from user space for RSA encryption/decryption. RSA function are implemented in linux kernel.

Currently, I found 2 way to call crypto API from user space:

- AF_ALG socket, using [libkapi] (http://www.chronox.de/libkcapi.html). It seems to be the offical solution (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/crypto/userspace-if.html).
- [cryptodev] (http://cryptodev-linux.org/) which uses ioctl.

Unfortunaly, cryptodev doesn't support asymmetric algorithms like RSA.

And I am not sur if AF_ALG supports akcipher like RSA. The result of `cat /proc/crypto` is:

```
...
name         : rsa
driver       : rsa-generic
module       : kernel
priority     : 100
refcnt       : 1
selftest     : passed
internal     : no
type         : akcipher
```

But, I tried to bind an AF_ALG socket with :

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_ALG, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0); 
struct sockaddr_alg sa = { 
    .salg_family = AF_ALG, 
    .salg_type = "akcipher",
    .salg_name = "rsa"
};
```

The bind failed with `***ERROR : bind socket failed (2) : No such file or directory`.

Did I miss something ? Is there an other way to call crypto API from user space ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `user-interface`?

Comment: Just use openssl or the like.

Comment: openssl implements a software solution without using kernel space API (and without hardware acceleration)

Comment: @tom OpenSSL is capable of using hardware acceleration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The kernel crypto API is accessible from user space. Currently, the
>   following ciphers are accessible:
>
> - Message digest including keyed message digest (HMAC, CMAC)
> - Symmetric ciphers
> - AEAD ciphers
> - Random Number Generators

This means, that the `akcipher` cipher family is not available from userspace, hence binding to it fails with `ENOENT`. Indeed, checking with the linux kernel source reveals, that there is no `algif_akcipher.c`, where the userspace interface of the akcipher family would be implemented.